# User notification needs context

Tags: android, android-context

In order to notify a user I use an AlertDialog or a Snanckbar. They both need an Activity context in order to display. Three cases:

- message produced from the current activity: that's trivial
- message produced from another thread: I am implementing a broadcast/receiver pattern so the thread can broadcast the message and the activity receives and shows the message
- message produced from a closing activity, eg activity Master start activity Selector, the user selects an option, the code do some stuff and then go back to Master

  ```
  // Selector activity draft sample
  mButtonSeelcted.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      super.onClick(view);
      doMagicForSelected();
      mContext.sendBroadcast(intentForUserMessage);
      mContext.startActivity(intentToMasterActivity);
    }
  });
  ```

Now the message is not displayed because by the time the receiver kicks in, the Selector activity is finished. Plus it gives a WindowLeaked exception as the AlertDialog is never dismissed.

Any thoughts? Is there a pattern I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am implementing a broadcast/receiver pattern so the thread can broadcast the message and the activity receives and shows the message

Please use an in-process message bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus). Using system broadcasts not only wastes CPU and battery, but it also introduces security issues (e.g., any app can spy on your messages).

> Is there a pattern I am missing?

In your third scenario, it is the responsibility of the "master activity" to show this information, not the activity that is being destroyed. So, add information to the `Intent` that you pass to `startActivity()` that tells the "master activity" to show that information.

Comment: Thanks for the performance/security tip :)
If the doMagicGorSelected method gets an exeption that can be broadcasted to the user (eg network problems) then it will broadcast the message. This method doesn't know about the Master.
I guess my point is how should I handle the fact that the context is volatile and can be destroyed/changed while I am using it.

Comment: @denispyr: "I guess my point is how should I handle the fact that the context is volatile and can be destroyed/changed while I am using it" -- if the master is the one showing the dialog or snackbar, then there is no volatility, and so I do not understand the concern.

Comment: let me clarify. With regards to my draft code, if 'doMagicForSelected() gets an "displayable" exception (eg bad input) it will broadcast that message. The Selector activity will receive it and show a dialog. If this is happens during onLoadFinished then no problems, the dialog will show. If it is happening before the activity finished then I am in trouble. Is there a pattern to follow for this case?

Comment: @denispyr: Most likely, the answer is "do not show the error" in that case. There are methods on `Activity` such as `isDestroyed()` and `isFinishing()` that you can use to help detect this. Or, better, when you switch to the event bus, only pay attention to events when you are in position to act upon them (e.g., register for events in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`).

Comment: I do use onResume/onPause in order to register/unregister. I will try the isXxx methods you are suggesting and maybe refactor the code. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the **Selector** activity (activity B) from **Master** activity (activity A) using startActivityForResult().
2. Display the dialog from **Master** activity as per the result.